# File permission issue with mongo docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker, jenkins, permissions

I'm trying to instanciate a mongodb docker image using the following commmand:

```
docker run -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mongo
```

The command fails instantly because of a **Persmission denied**:

```
2019-11-12T20:16:29.503+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid: Permission denied
```

The weird thing is the same command works fine on some other machines that has the same users, groups... The only thing that differs is the docker version.

I don't understand why the mongo instance does not run as I do not have any volumes or user specified on the command line.

Here is my docker info

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
Server:
 Containers: 29
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 28
 Images: 87
 Server Version: 19.03.4
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc version: 3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.9.0-11-amd64
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 25.52GiB
 Name: jenkins-vm
 ID: YIGQ:YOVJ:2Y7F:LM77:VHK6:ICMY:QDGA:5EFD:ZYDD:EQM5:DR77:DANT
 Docker Root Dir: /data/var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

And as suggested by @jan-garaj, here is the result of `docker run -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mongo id`: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

What could be the reason of this failure ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with some security configuration. Check and compare `docker info` outputs. You may have enabled user namespaces (`userns-remap`), some special seccomp, selinux policies, weird storage driver, full disk space, ...

Comment: The docker info are the same

Comment: @benjamin.d please attach `docker info` output to the + `docker run -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mongo id`

Answer (score 0):

Could be because of the selinux policy :

edit config file at /etc/selinux/config :

```
SELINUX:disabled
```

reboot your system and try to run the image after.

Comment: I tried, but that did not work. I get the exact same result